# How to animate the rear view controller on top of front view controller on toggling in SWRevealViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using the SWRevealViewController to load front and rear views. As of now, the default behaviour is that when the front view is swiped, the rear view is shown under the front view. This is making some of the portion of the rear view to hide behind the front view.

[image: This is how it looks like]

As shown in the image, the text boxes in the rear view are getting truncated. Is there a way I can show the rear view on top of the front view? This will mean that on swiping the screen from left to right, the front view shall not move to the right. Instead, the rear view shall appear on top of the front view. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Suggestions are also welcome about any other third party libraries that are capable of doing this.

Comment: You can't do that with swrevealviewcontroller. try another 3rd party library or if you don't want a separate ViewController for Rear View, add a gesture recogniser to your front View & then display the Rear UIView with animation.

Comment: if that is true, it is one of the saddest realities I've had to confront in recent times.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SWRevealViewController.m file there is a method

```
 - (void)_initDefaultProperties
```

in this method there is a variable name

```
 _rearViewRevealWidth = 220.0f;//change value and make it screen width.
 _rightViewRevealWidth = 320.0f;//change value and make it screen width.
```

Comment: You may not realize this, but you have saved me from a flogging :p ... Thanks! This solution does not obviously bring the rear view to the top, but is helping me to steer clear of the truncation problem.